# Is it possible to focus a control in a form that is unfocusable via WS_CHILD style?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've created a drop-down control similar to a ComboBox, where on the click of a button a 'dropdown' form will appear below the button and the user will be able to select an option from a ListBox. The dropdown form itself is unfocusable, so the parent form never loses focus. It all works perfectly as intended, but my problem is that I would like to be use any type of control in this dropdown form. Any control that requires focus to function (e.g. a TextBox) won't work because it will be unable to gain focus since the dropdown form is unfocusable.

I am using this code here for the dropdown form:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams ret = base.CreateParams;
        ret.Style = (int)Flags.WindowStyles.WS_CHILD;
        ret.ExStyle |= (int)Flags.WindowStyles.WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | (int)Flags.WindowStyles.WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;
        ret.X = this.Location.X;
        ret.Y = this.Location.Y;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Which I sourced from here:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71808/Creating-a-Form-That-Doesn-t-Take-Focus

I tried manually setting a dropdown control's parent to the root form, but this causes it not to be drawn.

I'd like to know if there's some kind of solution to allow selection of these controls contained in the dropdown despite the form itself being unselectable. Perhaps a windows message that I can process to circumvent focus logic?

Comment: Maybe remove the CreateParams override and add this other `protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation => true;`. Make the Form border-less (so it's shown as `WS_CHILD` would, but not actually a child): in this case, it won't steal the focus (the Focus is not moved from the calling Form) but all controls in the psudo-dropdown can be selected. You could also build a UserControl.

Comment: @Jimi Yeah, I've tried this when I was initially creating the dropdown. For whatever reason ShowWithoutActivation returning true has no effect, and still allows the form to be activated even calling OnActivated.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Returning `true` makes the internal `ShowParams` property to return `SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE` which is then used by the `SetVisibleCore()` call to show the Window. `OnActivated()` is not called until you intentionally move the Focus to that Form. As mentioned, use that override **alone**. Btw, when dealing with the Control's *internals*, you always need to specify what version of the Framework you're using. If you're not using 4.8, then migrate to this version. If you're using .Net Core...

Comment: @Jimi Alright, I had `TopMost` set to `true` which I believe is what caused `ShowWithoutActivation` to be ignored... Seems to show the form without activation if `TopMost` isn't set. I'm currently using .Net 4.5, I _should_ be able to migrate to 4.8. Regardless, at this point I'll have to do a bit of fiddling to return functionality to the dropdown to see if it works when not a child.

Comment: Well, you really don't want to set it TopMost there :) You could also use Show(this) in this context, the pseudo-dropdown will have the *right* owner from the start and still *float*. Note that some Control types can be parented to the Desktop... (but, yes, not as simple to manage). -- Unrelated: why target 4.5 in a new project? Do you need to support *ancient* Systems?

Comment: @Jimi I think I've got it all in more or less working order. Thanks for your help! It's not exactly a new project, I'm creating an editor for an existing project in the same solution, it's all migrated to 4.8 now though :).

Comment: I'm glad it helped:) Possibly, post the solution you adopted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up not using the `CreateParams` override, and instead simply used `protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation => true;` with a borderless form.

Seems to work well enough. Some of the benefits of not focusing controls such as selection borders and highlights had to be addressed case by case, but otherwise the looks the same with added functionality.